# Unable to find the Developer tab in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am unable to find the *Developer* tab in Excel. How can I enable it for writing VBA code?

Comment: With or without the Developer Tab you can access the VBA IDE by hitting `Alt`-`F11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default developer tab is hidden, if you want to use it, you need to enable it. You can follow the steps below: -

1. Take your mouse to any tab
2. Right click
3. Click on Customize the Ribbon
4. Check the Developer checkbox and click Ok

Check this article:  https://www.automationfever.com/vba/vba_enable_developer_tab.php

Or Watch this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHIoVFjXjxI&t=234s

Comment: Thanks for contributing an relevant answer.

Answer (score 5):

Steps:

1. Click on the *File* tab
2. Go to *Options* (present at left-bottom)
3. Go To *Customise Ribbon Options*
4. In *Customise the Ribbon* tab, you will see the *Developer* checkbox. Click on it and Voila! You will be able to see *Developer* tab on the bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Developer** in the **Options** - **Customize ribbon**
[image]

[image]